# Camtasia Studio 7 - Cursor flickering while recording

Tags: screen-recorder, camtasia

I'm using Camtasia Studio 7 to record my screen. While recording the cursor is heavily flickering. Is there a way to fix this? (I'm using Windows XP)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in Camtasia Studio 6. Hopefully the fix still stands...
In the recording toolbar, go to Tools > Options.
In the resulting window, uncheck the Capture Layered Windows option.
You should then find that the cursor stops flickering and moves smoothly. However, please be aware that there are some things it won't record in this mode, such as mouse click on explorer windows above the window you choose to record.
I hope that helps.
All the best,
Franco